# Getting -1 in index?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

How can this row give back -1 in index? i have no clue how. there is none of em that can have -1 in index all of them are lists? The lists have values 148, 2999, 620

```
products.prestaShopCategoryId2.Add(categories2.CategoryPrestaId[categories2.NewCategoryId.FindIndex(a => a.Contains(products.productCategoryId2[j]))]);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does exactly what the docs say it should

Comment: yea do so im sorry im eaven up for deleting it if so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to refactor this code, as it is very hard to read and problems like the one you have becaome very hard to solve. Please, see below code:

```
var indexOfItem = categories2.NewCategoryId.FindIndex(a => a.Contains(products.productCategoryId2[j]));
// Here you can handle situation, when element is not found and
// returned index is -1
if(indexOfItem == -1)
  throw new Exception("Item not found!");

var itemToAdd = categories2.CategoryPrestaId[indexOfItem];

products.prestaShopCategoryId2.Add(itemToAdd);
```

Additionally, you add some logging along the way or anything that will make your life easier, etc.

Comment: Yep will do i got it after i said it haha but yea thanks for the answer my brain was allittle bit slow

Comment: Voting up, for both right answer and code readability. Code should always be easy to read, don't worry about allocating one more variable to make your code more readable, unless you need to run on really limited resources. Even raspberry pi zero comes with 1GB of ram.

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.8

> Returns Int32 The zero-based index of the first occurrence of an
>   element that matches the conditions defined by match, if found;
>   otherwise, -1.

When not found, it is -1.

Comment: Add the item to the collection so it can be found, or specify the correct categoryid so it can be found. Hard to answer, it's up to you.